# Storybook-tailwind. How should I add tailwind to storybook

Tags: reactjs, typescript, webpack, tailwind-css, storybook

I want to add tailwind to storybook. So that Stories will render just like it will render on web.

I used `create-react-app project-name --template typescript` to create the project.

Then to install the tailwind I followed this https://tailwindcss.com/docs/guides/create-react-app  instruction from the documentation of tailwind.

Once I finished it I ran the code `npm sb init`. Which made sure that storybook ran.

Now I need to tell storybook to use tailwindcss for styling. But I have no idea how.

Every other answer I saw tells to edit `postcss.config.js` files.

But I followed this https://tailwindcss.com/docs/guides/create-react-app documentation where I didnt even have to create postcss.config.js file. So I am confused to what to do now.

For clarity I will include some configuration file below.

`craco.config.js`

```
module.exports = {
    style: {
      postcss: {
        plugins: [
          require('tailwindcss'),
          require('autoprefixer'),
        ],
      },
    },
  }
```

`.storybook/preview.js`

```
import "../src/index.css"

export const parameters = {
  actions: { argTypesRegex: "^on[A-Z].*" },
}
```

`.storybook/main.js`

```
module.exports = {
  "stories": [
    "../src/**/*.stories.mdx",
    "../src/**/*.stories.@(js|jsx|ts|tsx)"
  ],
  "addons": [
    "@storybook/addon-links",
    "@storybook/addon-essentials",
    "@storybook/preset-create-react-app"
  ]
}
```

`src/index.css`

```
@tailwind base;
@tailwind components;
@tailwind utilities;
```

`tailwind.config.js`

```
module.exports = {
  purge: ['./src/**/*.{js,jsx,ts,tsx}', './public/index.html'],

  darkMode: false, // or 'media' or 'class'
  theme: {
    extend: {},
  },
  variants: {
    extend: {},
  },
  plugins: [],
}
```

`package.json`

```
`{
  "name": "memory",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "@craco/craco": "^6.0.0",
    "@tailwindcss/postcss7-compat": "^2.0.2",
    "@testing-library/jest-dom": "^5.11.4",
    "@testing-library/react": "^11.1.0",
    "@testing-library/user-event": "^12.1.10",
    "@types/jest": "^26.0.15",
    "@types/node": "^12.0.0",
    "@types/react": "^16.14.2",
    "@types/react-dom": "^16.9.8",
    "autoprefixer": "^9.8.6",
    "postcss": "^7.0.35",
    "react": "^17.0.1",
    "react-dom": "^17.0.1",
    "react-scripts": "4.0.1",
    "tailwindcss": "npm:@tailwindcss/postcss7-compat@^2.0.2",
    "typescript": "^4.0.3",
    "web-vitals": "^0.2.4"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "start": "craco start",
    "build": "craco build",
    "test": "craco test",
    "eject": "react-scripts eject",
    "storybook": "start-storybook -p 6006 -s public",
    "build-storybook": "build-storybook -s public"
  },
  "eslintConfig": {
    "extends": [
      "react-app",
      "react-app/jest"
    ]
  },
  "browserslist": {
    "production": [
      ">0.2%",
      "not dead",
      "not op_mini all"
    ],
    "development": [
      "last 1 chrome version",
      "last 1 firefox version",
      "last 1 safari version"
    ]
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@storybook/addon-actions": "^6.1.11",
    "@storybook/addon-essentials": "^6.1.11",
    "@storybook/addon-links": "^6.1.11",
    "@storybook/node-logger": "^6.1.11",
    "@storybook/preset-create-react-app": "^3.1.5",
    "@storybook/react": "^6.1.11"
  }
}
```

`tsconfig.json`

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "target": "es5",
    "lib": [
      "dom",
      "dom.iterable",
      "esnext"
    ],
    "allowJs": true,
    "skipLibCheck": true,
    "esModuleInterop": true,
    "allowSyntheticDefaultImports": true,
    "strict": true,
    "forceConsistentCasingInFileNames": true,
    "noFallthroughCasesInSwitch": true,
    "module": "esnext",
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "resolveJsonModule": true,
    "isolatedModules": true,
    "noEmit": true,
    "jsx": "react-jsx"
  },
  "include": [
    "src"
  ]
}
```

Answer (score 76, accepted):

Storybook [recommends](https://github.com/storybookjs/storybook/blob/next/MIGRATION.md#deprecated-implicit-postcss-loader) using the [`@storybook/addon-postcss`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/@storybook/addon-postcss) for customizing the postCSS config from now on (instead of relying on customizing the `postcss-loader`):

1. Add the postCSS addon to your installation

   ```sh
   npm i -D @storybook/addon-postcss     # or
   yarn add -D @storybook/addon-postcss
   ```
2. Create the [`postcss.config.js`](https://tailwindcss.com/docs/installation/using-postcss) in the project root

   ```js
   // postcss.config.js
   module.exports = {
     plugins: {
       tailwindcss: {},
       autoprefixer: {},
     }
   }
   ```
3. Add the plugin to your `.storybook/main.js`

   ```js
   // .storybook/main.js
   module.exports = {
     ...
     addons: [
       ...
       {
         name: '@storybook/addon-postcss',
         options: {
           cssLoaderOptions: {
             // When you have splitted your css over multiple files
             // and use @import('./other-styles.css')
             importLoaders: 1,
           },
           postcssLoaderOptions: {
             // When using postCSS 8
             implementation: require('postcss'),
           },
         },
       },
     ],
   };
   ```
4. Import your css file in the `.storybook/preview.js`

   ```js
   // .storybook/preview.js
   import '../src/styles.css';
   ```

Comment: This didn't work for me for some reason. FWIW, I'm using postcss7 as this is recommended in the install page on tailwind. 
```
SyntaxError

(1:1) Unknown word

> 1 | var api = require("!../node_modules/style-loader/dist/runtime/injectStylesIntoStyleTag.js");
    | ^
  2 |             var content = require("!!../node_modules/css-loader/dist/cjs.js??ref--10-1!../node_modules/postcss-loader/dist/cjs.js!./index.css");
```

Comment: Tailwind requires PostCSS 8 (not 7) as stated in the docs: https://tailwindcss.com/docs/installation#install-tailwind-via-npm

Comment: it's not working for me

Comment: CRA doesn't support PostCSS 8 though, so you need to install a postcss 7 compat build: https://tailwindcss.com/docs/guides/create-react-app

Comment: @cgat How do i install a postcss 7 compatible build?

Comment: The tailwindcss link above used to describe how to do this (they had a special postcss7 compat build you would install. Looks like things might have changed and potentially postcss 8 is now supported.

Comment: I could NOT get addon-postcss working in 2022, but the `webpackFinal` config from the top voted answer did work. I kept getting "Unknown word" errors like https://github.com/storybookjs/addon-postcss/issues/33 no matter what config I tried, and agree with the comment there that it's basically abandoned (tons of neglected issues and no commits in 16 months).

Answer (score 64):

You're almost there.

The missing piece of your config is to add a webpack configuration to apply tailwind to `postcss-loader`:

```js
const path = require('path')

module.exports = {
  stories: [
    '../src/**/*.stories.mdx', 
    '../src/**/*.stories.@(js|jsx|ts|tsx)'
  ],
  addons: [
    '@storybook/addon-links',
    '@storybook/addon-essentials',
    '@storybook/preset-create-react-app',
  ],
  webpackFinal: async (config) => {
    config.module.rules.push({
      test: /\.css$/,
      use: [
        {
          loader: 'postcss-loader',
          options: {
            postcssOptions: {
              plugins: [
                require('tailwindcss'),
                require('autoprefixer'),
              ],
            },
          },
        },
      ],
      include: path.resolve(__dirname, '../'),
    })
    return config
  },
}
```

Comment: Maybe you should create a boilerplate for this

Comment: Oops, I just had to add ```import "../src/index.css"``` in **.storybook/preview.js** 

Comment: @sudo_kaizen I added a storybook design system to a boilerplate I maintain, maybe this could help

Comment: Which version of `postcss-loader` should I use with a React library? I ran `npm install postcss-loader` but am getting an error in the `loader` function of `postcss-loader/dist/index.js` saying that `this.getOptions is not a function`.

Comment: [Check this out](https://stackoverflow.com/a/64620666/4420543) for newer `postcss` versions

Comment: How can I use tailwind and postcss without webpack? Also using rollup to export the library.

Comment: I also had to add `import "../src/index.css"` in *.storybook/preview.js* like @AlaDouagi to make it works.

Comment: I had to import the CSS and change the options field as follows: 
`options: { postcssOptions: { plugins: [require("tailwindcss"), require("autoprefixer")]}}`

See [this link](https://github.com/ckeditor/ckeditor5/issues/8315#issuecomment-714313936) for details, and sorry for the formatting!

Comment: Confirmed, like @JohnMcCollum I got it working after changing to nested `postcssOptions` and getting rid of `ident`. Could you update this answer for 2022?

Answer (score 12):

TAILWIND STORYBOOK CRA [2022-2023(hopefully)]

package.json

```
"devDependencies": {
    "@storybook/addon-actions": "^6.5.9",
    "@storybook/addon-essentials": "^6.5.9",
    "@storybook/addon-interactions": "^6.5.9",
    "@storybook/addon-links": "^6.5.9",
    "@storybook/addon-postcss": "^2.0.0",
    "@storybook/builder-webpack5": "^6.5.9",
    "@storybook/manager-webpack5": "^6.5.9",
    "@storybook/node-logger": "^6.5.9",
    "@storybook/preset-create-react-app": "^4.1.2",
    "@storybook/react": "^6.5.9",
    "@storybook/testing-library": "^0.0.13",
    "@typescript-eslint/eslint-plugin": "^5.28.0",
    "@typescript-eslint/parser": "^5.28.0",
    "autoprefixer": "^10.4.7",
    "babel-plugin-named-exports-order": "^0.0.2",
    "eslint": "^8.17.0",
    "eslint-config-airbnb": "^19.0.4",
    "eslint-plugin-import": "^2.26.0",
    "eslint-plugin-jsx-a11y": "^6.5.1",
    "eslint-plugin-react": "^7.30.0",
    "eslint-plugin-react-hooks": "^4.6.0",
    "eslint-plugin-simple-import-sort": "^7.0.0",
    "postcss": "^8.4.14",
    "tailwindcss": "^3.1.1",
    "webpack": "^5.73.0"
  }
```

tailwind.config.js

```
module.exports = {
    content: [
        "./src/**/*.{js,jsx,ts,tsx}",
    ],
    theme: {
        extend: {},
    },
    plugins: [],
}
```

postcss.config.js

```
module.exports = {
  plugins: {
    tailwindcss: {},
    autoprefixer: {},
  },
}
```

.storybook/main.js

```
module.exports = {
  stories: [
    "../src/**/*.stories.mdx",
    "../src/**/*.stories.@(js|jsx|ts|tsx)"
  ],
  addons: [
    "@storybook/addon-links",
    "@storybook/addon-essentials",
    "@storybook/addon-interactions",
    "@storybook/preset-create-react-app",
    {
      name: '@storybook/addon-postcss',
      options: {
        postcssLoaderOptions: {
          implementation: require('postcss'),
        },
      },
    },
  ],
  framework: "@storybook/react",
  core: {
    "builder": "@storybook/builder-webpack5"
  }
}
```

.storybook/preview.js

```
import '!style-loader!css-loader!postcss-loader!tailwindcss/tailwind.css';

export const parameters = {
  actions: { argTypesRegex: "^on[A-Z].*" },
  controls: {
    matchers: {
      color: /(background|color)$/i,
      date: /Date$/,
    },
  },
}
```

Comment: The last import string is essential. Why do we have to write this import instead of the default `tailwindcss/tailwind.css` import?

Comment: @newguy I think it is the place which styles are generated in mount.

Comment: Thanks, is is what worked for me!

Answer (score 6):

The answer was right but in the latest CRA I have to config like this:

```js
config.module.rules.push({
      test: /\.css$/,
      use: [
        {
          loader: "postcss-loader",
          options: {
            // HERE: OPTIONS
            postcssOptions: {
              plugins: [require("tailwindcss"), require("autoprefixer")],
            },
          },
        },
      ],
      include: path.resolve(__dirname, "../"),
    });
```

Comment: This did not work for me in latest CRA. The accepted answer works fine.

Answer (score 5):

Similar to ofhouse's answer, but here is a solution if you don't want to have an extra `postcss.config.js` for only a few lines or if you want use typescript in everything (as the loader doesn't pick up postcss.config.ts)

1. Add the official postCSS addon

```sh
npm i -D @storybook/addon-postcss
yarn add -D @storybook/addon-postcss
```

2. Config main.ts & tailwind.config.ts

```
/* .stories/main.ts */

import postcss from 'postcss';
import * as tailwindcss from '../tailwind.config';

import type { StorybookConfig } from '@storybook/react/types';

export const addons: StorybookConfig['addons'] = [
  // other addons,
  {
    name: '@storybook/addon-postcss',
    options: {
      postcssLoaderOptions: {
        implementation: postcss,
        postcssOptions: {
          plugins: {
            tailwindcss, // or you can nest your options entirely here
            autoprefixer: {
              // autoprefixer options
            },
          },
        },
      },
    },
  },
];
```

```
/* tailwind.config.ts */

import type { TailwindConfig } from 'tailwindcss/tailwind-config';

export const theme: TailwindConfig['theme'] = {
  // theme options
}

// other options
```

Answer (score 2):

I  could "fix it" by running the tailwind-CLI and building the global.css file and importing it to `./storybook/preview.js`

here's the cli command used.

```bash
npx tailwindcss -i ./src/styles/global.css -o ./.storybook/global.css --watch
```

then import it from the output path (-o flag) in the command above.

```js
// ./storybook/preview.js

import './global.css';
...
```

Comment: Added this line to my script for storybook. 
None of the other solutions worked, unfortunately.

Comment: Storybook v7 now have support try this addon @storybook/addon-styling

Comment: The "solution" from @storybook didnt work either.

Answer (score 0):

This recipe assumes that you have a React app using Tailwind CSS and have just set up Storybook >=7.0 using the getting started guide. Don’t have this? Follow Tailwind's setup instructions then run:

## Add Storybook:

```
npx storybook@latest init
```

Add the @storybook/addon-styling package to your DevDependencies

```
yarn add -D @storybook/addon-styling
```

Then register with Storybook in .storybook/main.js.

```
module.exports = {
  stories: ['../stories/**/*.mdx', '../stories/**/*.stories.@(js|jsx|ts|tsx)'],
  addons: ['@storybook/addon-essentials', '@storybook/addon-styling'],
};
```