# Storybook with TailwindCSS in React (CRACO) and PostCSS does nothing

Tags: javascript, reactjs, webpack, tailwind-css, storybook

I've been trying to get Storybook to work with TailwindCSS in a CRA. However, I am unable to use any TailwindCSS classes and am getting this message when I start Storybook:

```
44% building 284/307 modules 23 active ...Documents\GitHub\<my project name>\node_modules\core-js\internals\set-to-string-tag.jsYou did not set any plugins, parser, or stringifier. Right now, PostCSS does nothing. Pick plugins for your case on https://www.postcss.parts/ and use them in postcss.config.js.
44% building 287/307 modules 20 active ...Documents\GitHub\<my project name>\node_modules\core-js\internals\set-to-string-tag.jsYou did not set any plugins, parser, or stringifier. Right now, PostCSS does nothing. Pick plugins for your case on https://www.postcss.parts/ and use them in postcss.config.js.
51% building 347/375 modules 28 active ...cuments\GitHub\<my project name>\node_modules\core-js\modules\es.symbol.unscopables.jsYou did not set any plugins, parser, or stringifier. Right now, PostCSS does nothing. Pick plugins for your case on https://www.postcss.parts/ and use them in postcss.config.js.
69% building 1065/1075 modules 10 active ...uments\GitHub\<my project name>\node_modules\core-js\modules\es.number.is-integer.jsYou did not set any plugins, parser, or stringifier. Right now, PostCSS does nothing. Pick plugins for your case on https://www.postcss.parts/ and use them in postcss.config.js
```

I've followed this [guide](https://medium.com/storybookjs/building-a-front-end-project-with-react-tailwindcss-and-storybook-742bdb1417da). I've also checked the [question here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65495912/storybook-tailwind-how-should-i-add-tailwind-to-storybook), and here's `package.json`:

```
{
  "name": "some-project-name",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "private": true,
  "engine": {
    "node": "^16.5.0"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "@craco/craco": "6.2.0",
    "@testing-library/jest-dom": "5.11.4",
    "@testing-library/react": "11.1.0",
    "@testing-library/user-event": "12.1.10",
    "express": "4.17.1",
    "react": "17.0.2",
    "react-dom": "17.0.2",
    "react-router-dom": "5.2.0",
    "react-scripts": "4.0.3",
    "styled-components": "5.3.0",
    "web-vitals": "1.0.1"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "start": "craco start",
    "build": "craco build",
    "test": "craco test",
    "eject": "react-scripts eject",
    "prod:test": "yarn build && node server.js",
    "prod:start": "yarn build && pm2-runtime server.js",
    "dev:up": "docker-compose -f docker-compose.yml -f docker-compose.dev.yml up",
    "dev:force": "docker-compose down && docker-compose -f docker-compose.yml -f docker-compose.dev.yml up",
    "prod:up": "docker-compose -f docker-compose.yml -f docker-compose.prod.yml up",
    "prod:force": "docker-compose down && docker-compose -f docker-compose.yml -f docker-compose.prod.yml up",
    "docker:build": "docker build .",
    "storybook": "start-storybook -p 6006 -s public",
    "build-storybook": "build-storybook -s public"
  },
  "eslintConfig": {
    "extends": [
      "react-app",
      "react-app/jest"
    ],
    "overrides": [
      {
        "files": [
          "**/*.stories.*"
        ],
        "rules": {
          "import/no-anonymous-default-export": "off"
        }
      }
    ]
  },
  "browserslist": {
    "production": [
      ">0.2%",
      "not dead",
      "not op_mini all"
    ],
    "development": [
      "last 1 chrome version",
      "last 1 firefox version",
      "last 1 safari version"
    ]
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@storybook/addon-actions": "6.3.5",
    "@storybook/addon-essentials": "6.3.5",
    "@storybook/addon-links": "6.3.5",
    "@storybook/node-logger": "6.3.5",
    "@storybook/preset-create-react-app": "3.2.0",
    "@storybook/react": "6.3.5",
    "autoprefixer": "9",
    "postcss": "7",
    "tailwindcss": "npm:@tailwindcss/postcss7-compat"
  },
  "resolutions": {
    "babel-loader": "8.1.0"
  }
}
```

Here's the `craco.config.js`:

```
module.exports = {
    style: {
        postcss: {
            plugins: [require('tailwindcss'), require('autoprefixer')],
        },
    },
};
```

`.storybook/main.js`:

```
const path = require('path');

module.exports = {
    stories: ['../src/**/*.stories.mdx', '../src/**/*.stories.@(js|jsx|ts|tsx)'],
    addons: ['@storybook/addon-links', '@storybook/addon-essentials', '@storybook/preset-create-react-app'],
    webpackFinal: async (config) => {
        config.module.rules.push({
            test: /\.css$/,
            use: [
                {
                    loader: 'postcss-loader',
                    options: {
                        // HERE: OPTIONS
                        postcssOptions: {
                            plugins: [require('tailwindcss'), require('autoprefixer')],
                        },
                    },
                },
            ],
            include: path.resolve(__dirname, '../'),
        });
        return config;
    },
};
```

`postcss.config.js` (which I don't think matters here but just in case):

```
const tailwindcss = require('tailwindcss');

module.exports = {
    plugins: [
        tailwindcss('./tailwind.config.js'),
        require('autoprefixer'),
    ],
};
```

`tailwind.config.js`:

```
module.exports = {
    purge: ['./src/**/*.{js,jsx,ts,tsx}', './public/index.html'],
    darkMode: false, // or 'media' or 'class'
    theme: {
        fontFamily: {
            sans: ['Montserrat'],
        },
        extend: {
            screens: {
                mx: '2048px',
            },
        },
        variants: {
            extend: {},
        },
        plugins: [],
    },
};
```

I'm not able to use TailwindCSS styles in my stories components.

Here's the demo Button component:

```
import React from 'react';
import PropTypes from 'prop-types';
import './button.css';

/**
 * Primary UI component for user interaction
 */
export const Button = ({ primary, backgroundColor, size, label, ...props }) => {
    return (
        <button type="button" className="bg-gray-900" {...props}>
            {label}
        </button>
    );
};

Button.propTypes = {
    /**
     * Is this the principal call to action on the page?
     */
    primary: PropTypes.bool,
    /**
     * What background color to use
     */
    backgroundColor: PropTypes.string,
    /**
     * How large should the button be?
     */
    size: PropTypes.oneOf(['small', 'medium', 'large']),
    /**
     * Button contents
     */
    label: PropTypes.string.isRequired,
    /**
     * Optional click handler
     */
    onClick: PropTypes.func,
};

Button.defaultProps = {
    backgroundColor: null,
    primary: false,
    size: 'medium',
    onClick: undefined,
};
```

The Button:
[image]

HTML in DOM:
`<button type="button" class="bg-gray-900">Button</button>`

Not sure where to go from here...

Update:

Went to webpack and postcss docs, and removed the options from `.storyboard/main.js` so use just looks like this:

```
use: [
                {
                    loader: 'postcss-loader',
                },
            ],
```

Now it's actually grabbing the plugins from `postcss.config.js`:

```
module.exports = {
    plugins: [require('autoprefixer'), require('tailwindcss')],
};
```

So the warning about no plugins found went away. But still no visible change on the website.