# How to configure Storybook JS with Tailwind CSS for a pre-existing React application

Tags: reactjs, next.js, tailwind-css, storybook, postcss

I'm working on a TypeScript-React-Next.js-Tailwind CSS application.

I've been trying to configure Storybook with Tailwind CSS. I tried adding PostCSS as an add on as instructed in the docs to no avail.

Current `main.js` file in **.storybook**:

```
const path = require('path')

module.exports = {
  "stories": [
    "../src/**/*.stories.mdx",
    "../src/**/*.stories.@(js|jsx|ts|tsx)"
  ],
  "addons": [
    "@storybook/addon-links",
    "@storybook/addon-essentials",
    "@storybook/preset-create-react-app"
  ],
  webpackFinal: async (config) => {
    config.module.rules.push({
      test: /\,css&/,
      use: [
        {
          loader: 'postcss-loader',
          options: {
            ident: 'postcss',
            plugins: [
              require('tailwindcss'),
              require('autoprefixer')
            ]
          }
        }
      ],
      include: path.resolve(__dirname, '../'),
    })
    return config
  }
}
```

Current `package.json`:

```
{
  "name": "vimi",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "private": true,
  "scripts": {
    "codegen": "graphql-codegen --config codegen.yml",
    "dev": "next dev",
    "build": "next build && next export",
    "start": "next start",
    "lint": "next lint",
    "storybook": "start-storybook -p 6006",
    "build-storybook": "build-storybook"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "@apollo/client": "^3.4.7",
    "@auth0/auth0-react": "^1.6.0",
    "@aws-amplify/ui-react": "^1.2.20",
    "@graphql-tools/merge": "^7.0.0",
    "@graphql-tools/schema": "^8.0.3",
    "@headlessui/react": "^1.3.0",
    "@heroicons/react": "^1.0.1",
    "@hookform/resolvers": "^2.8.2",
    "aws-amplify": "^4.3.2",
    "aws-appsync-auth-link": "^3.0.6",
    "date-fns": "^2.25.0",
    "graphql": "^15.5.1",
    "immer": "^9.0.5",
    "jotai": "^1.1.2",
    "next": "^12.0.1",
    "phin": "^3.6.0",
    "react": "17.0.2",
    "react-dom": "17.0.2",
    "react-google-button": "^0.7.2",
    "react-hook-form": "^7.17.1",
    "yup": "^0.32.9"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@babel/core": "^7.16.5",
    "@graphql-codegen/cli": "^2.1.1",
    "@graphql-codegen/import-types-preset": "^2.0.0",
    "@graphql-codegen/typescript": "^2.1.2",
    "@graphql-codegen/typescript-operations": "^2.0.1",
    "@graphql-codegen/typescript-react-apollo": "^3.0.0",
    "@storybook/addon-actions": "^6.4.9",
    "@storybook/addon-essentials": "^6.4.9",
    "@storybook/addon-links": "^6.4.9",
    "@storybook/react": "^6.4.9",
    "@tailwindcss/forms": "^0.3.3",
    "@tailwindcss/postcss7-compat": "^2.2.17",
    "@types/react": "17.0.11",
    "autoprefixer": "^9.8.8",
    "babel-loader": "^8.2.3",
    "eslint": "7.28.0",
    "eslint-config-next": "11.0.0",
    "graphql-auto-transformer": "^1.3.1",
    "graphql-let": "^0.18.4",
    "import-sort-style-react2": "^0.3.6",
    "postcss": "^7.0.39",
    "prettier": "^2.3.2",
    "prettier-plugin-import-sort": "^0.0.7",
    "tailwindcss": "npm:@tailwindcss/postcss7-compat@^2.2.17",
    "typescript": "4.3.2",
    "yaml-loader": "^0.6.0"
  },
  "importSort": {
    ".js, .jsx, .ts, .tsx": {
      "style": "react2",
      "parser": "typescript"
    }
  }
}
```

I also followed the instruction in this [Medium](https://medium.com/storybookjs/building-a-front-end-project-with-react-tailwindcss-and-storybook-742bdb1417da) post and [Stack Overflow answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/68757745/12198222) without any luck.

Even though Storybook starts up fine, in the building process, I get the following error, and I see Tailwind CSS hasn't worked on my components (stories):

```
info @storybook/react v6.4.9
info 
info => Loading presets
ERR! Addon value should end in /register OR it should be a valid preset https://storybook.js.org/docs/react/addons/writing-presets/
ERR! @storybook/preset-create-react-app
```

I don't understand why this preset is invalid. Even when I simply put the add on:

```
module.exports = {
  "stories": [
    "../src/**/*.stories.mdx",
    "../src/**/*.stories.@(js|jsx|ts|tsx)"
  ],
  "addons": [
    "@storybook/addon-links",
    "@storybook/addon-essentials",
    "@storybook/addon-postcss",
  ],
  "framework": "@storybook/react"
}
```

I get the error:

```
info @storybook/react v6.4.9
info 
info => Loading presets
ERR! Addon value should end in /register OR it should be a valid preset https://storybook.js.org/docs/react/addons/writing-presets/
ERR! @storybook/addon-postcss
```

Any help would be much appreciated!

Comment: could you show the package.json as well?

Comment: @keikai I added the package.json snippet. Thanks!