# How to integrate Storybook with Tailwind CSS, Create Next App & TypeScript

Tags: typescript, next.js, tailwind-css, storybook, postcss

**The following question is related to a [previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70602533/how-to-configure-storybook-js-with-tailwind-css-for-a-pre-existing-react-applica) I asked, so apologies in advance if I'm being repetitive, but I still haven't been able to resolve my issue.*

I'm trying to get Storybook to work with Tailwind CSS to no avail so far. These are the steps I've followed:

1. I have created a new TypeScript project from scratch, bootstrapping
   it with Create Next App. I followed the instructions on [Tailwinds website](https://tailwindcss.com/docs/guides/nextjs). Tailwind works fine on the App.
2. I set up Storybook following the instructions on [their website](https://storybook.js.org/docs/react/get-started/install). Storybook starts up fine on port 6006.
3. I configured the main.js file accordingly to incorporate PostCSS for Tailwind to work within Storybook:

```
module.exports = {
  "stories": [
    "../stories/**/*.stories.mdx",
    "../stories/**/*.stories.@(js|jsx|ts|tsx)"
  ],
  "addons": [
    "@storybook/addon-links",
    "@storybook/addon-essentials",
    "@storybook/addon-postcss"
  ],
  "framework": "@storybook/react"
}
```

Despite doing all these, I don't see any effect of Tailwind on the story components—only in the application.

I tried testing if Tailwind works by putting in a small element in a Storybook component. I don't see it rendered as expected:

```
<h1 className="text-3xl font-bold underline">
    Tailwind Works!
</h1>
```

Link to Github repo: https://github.com/TRahulSam1997/storybook-tailwind-next-typescript-v2

Any help would be much appreciated!

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Update!

Simply doing this worked:

Import

```
import 'tailwindcss/tailwind.css';
```

into **preview.js**

Thanks to https://stackoverflow.com/a/68022201/12198222

Answer (score 1):

Add the path to the stories folder in the tailwind.config.js file.

```js
module.exports = {
  content: [
    "./pages/**/*.{js,ts,jsx,tsx}",
    "./components/**/*.{js,ts,jsx,tsx}",
    "./stories/**/*.{js,ts,jsx,tsx}", //instruct tailwind to read the stories folder
  ],
  theme: {},
  plugins: [],
}
```