# MDX styling doesn't work after importing Tailwind CSS to Storybook

Tags: next.js, tailwind-css, storybook, postcss

I'm setting up a NextJS project with Tailwind and Storybook. The MDX styling doesn't work after importing Tailwind CSS

**Before importing Tailwind**

[image]

**After importing Tailwind**

[image]

**What I did**

The Tailwind CSS is being added to the storybook by following the answer at this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65495912/storybook-tailwind-how-should-i-add-tailwind-to-storybook)

`.storybook/main.js`

```
// Remove this code, MDX is working fine but Tailwind isn't
{
  name: '@storybook/addon-postcss',
  options: {
    postcssLoaderOptions: {
      implementation: require('postcss'),
    },
  },
},,
```

**Full code demo:**
https://github.com/tanwanjern/next-storybook-demo

**Question:**

How can I make Tailwind and MDX styling work together in Storybook? And which Storybook add-ons are not necessary so that I can remove them?

Comment: did you figure this out?